# Can I get an explaination of this short code that generates a random string in unicode?

Tags: c#, string, forms, for-loop, random

I'm currently in a c# class and wanted a full explaination of every line in this short code. I can see what happens in the form but I don't fully know how to explain it since some parts copied from the internet (new char[] for example) and how all of them work together. Thanks in advance would be a great help!

```
private void BtnSkapa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int längd = int.Parse(tbxLängd.Text);
    var lösen = new char[längd];
    string tecken = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!#¤%&?<>£${[]}§+@£$";
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < längd; i++)
    {
        lösen[i] = tecken[random.Next(tecken.Length)];
        lblLösen.Text = new string(lösen);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds quite a bit like a homework task. I'd recommed you add your own analysis to each line (which may very well be wrong) to show your own effort. The community here may then provide tips to improve, but you most probably won't find the solution here,

Comment: @AlexB Yeah I did that and believe I understand all except on why I need to use "new char[]"

Comment: new char[] simply allocates a fixed-length array, which makes sure the assignment `lösen[i] = tecken[...]` will not fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, some comments on the code:

```
private void BtnSkapa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int längd = int.Parse(tbxLängd.Text); // attempts to convert the String in (presumably) the TextBox "tbxLängd" to an integer
    var lösen = new char[längd]; // creates an ARRAY of char, with length "längd"
    string tecken = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!#¤%&?<>£${[]}§+@£$"; // "tecken" holds all the possible candidates to be chosen from
    Random random = new Random(); // creates an instance of the Random class so we can generate a random number below
    for (int i = 0; i < längd; i++) // setup a for loop that will iterate "längd" times
    {
        lösen[i] = tecken[random.Next(tecken.Length)]; // assign a random value from "tecken" to the current position in the "lösen" array
        lblLösen.Text = new string(lösen); // creates a string from the character array (this could be put OUTSIDE the for loop down below)
    }
}
```

Note that a character array is not necessarily required.  You could create a blank string and concatenate the next random value to the end of that.  There are many other ways to accomplish the same end goal...

```
Yeah I did that and believe I understand all except on why I need to use "new char[]"
```

In the code we are getting a random value from the source string with:

```
lösen[i] = tecken[random.Next(tecken.Length)];
```

This works because you can use an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netcore-3.1#Indexes) to access any position in the string as a char.  Since it returns a char, it makes sense to make an array of char.

Once the array is populated with chars, we create a string from that array by passing it to this [string constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_String__ctor_System_Char___).

Comment: Thanks! This answer really helped me understand some of these lines better.